# Is it a problem that studs are 3 feet apart in my townhome?

Tags: safety, structural, studs, new-home

We recently moved into a new build townhome. The studs appear to be 3 feet apart. My understanding is that they are suppose to be 16-24 inches apart. Is the structural integrity compromised by the studs being so far apart? I’m observing these findings in external walls!! Using a good quality stud finder to confirm my findings.

Comment: If just internal walls separating rooms not that much, but sign of builder being cheap.  Load bearing walls and external walls does not seem has good.  How are you checking for stud spacing?  Using a good stud finder?

Comment: What is your location on the globe?  Local codes will determine the rules, but assume that tract home builders will use as few materials as the inspector will let them get away with.

Comment: That would have NOT passed the inspection

Comment: Yeah, I have serious doubts that this is the case. What's your evidence?

Comment: Please clarify whether this is observed in interior, exterior, or common (shared with neighbor unit) walls. Also, is this in a basement or above grade?

Comment: @ChrisO  Measurements seem to indicate an American or older Canadian.  The young whipper snappers don't know how to measure right.

Comment: Stud spacing can run anywhere from 12" to 4 feet, depending on multiple factors.  The 24" norm is mainly linked to common drywall type construction.

Answer (score 2):

Occasionally you may see a case where the builder offset studs a bit from each other so even-numbered studs are in contact with and supporting the wallboard on one side and odd-numbered are in contact with and supporting the wallboard on the other. This improves sound isolation, by keeping the studs from coupling the two walls to each other. (In sound studios, the space between the wallboards may be filled with a deadening material like sand to provide further isolation.) All the studs are still there, and it's basically the same structurally but it's quieter. (Though obviously it's a bit more hassle to hang shelving and such.)

I have no idea whether that's what Les is seeing, but it would explain why studs are being found on 36" centers -- they're present every 18" as usual, but only half are being picked up by the studfinder.

Comment: Wouldn't it be heartwarming to hear this technique was thoughtfully used in the walls adjoining OP's townhouse units ....